# Non-tableau calculi for system K

Tags: logic, modal-logic, beth-tableau

**What proof calculi are there besides the method of analytic tableaux for System K?**

The method of analytic tableaux is tricky to typeset and takes a lot of space, especially for modal logic.

I'm especially interested in alternatives that are more compact or easier to typeset. I'm also interested in alternatives that are worse by these criteria because it's nice to know what the options are.

---

I'm attempting to prove the following inference rule, which holds in system $K$.

$$ \frac{\square(A \to B) \;\; \text{and}\;\; \square(A)}{\square(B)}$$

By the truth conditions of negation in system K, this is equivalent to the following

$$ \frac{\square(A \to B) \;\; \text{and} \;\; \square(A) \;\; \text{and} \;\; \lnot\square(B)}{\bot} $$

Proving it using a world-labeled tableau is possible, but takes up a lot of space. I keep track of the accessibility graph of the worlds named so far with a list of accessibility assumptions up at the top.

```
accessibility assumptions:
⟨w,w'⟩ ∈ R


  w:□(A→B)
  w:□(¬A∨B)
    |
  w:□A
    |
  w:¬□B
  w:◊¬B
    |
  w':¬B
    |
 w':¬A∨B
    |
   w':A
  /    \
w':¬A   w':B     
  |        |
contra    contra
```

This particular tableau calculus allows elimination of $\lozenge$ by creating a *fresh* world and allows inferring $\varphi$ in any accessible *destination* world if $\square \varphi$ holds in the *source* world. Every proposition is explicitly labeled with the world where it holds. This is the method described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux#World-labeled_tableau).

Comment: Can't you just take your favorite proof calculus for propositional logic (e.g. natural deduction or a sequent calculus) and add the necessitation rule and axiom K?

Comment: @AlexKruckman, That's a good question; I'm not sure. I think the necessitation rule is a little bit tricky. I think I can (for example) take a Hilbert system with modus ponens [like one of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems#Classical_propositional_calculus_systems), add $\square \varphi$ for all propositional tautologies $\varphi$ as axioms, and add $\square(a \to b) \to \square(a) \to \square(b)$ as an additional axiom. Is that the idea that you were referring to for extending a proof caclulus for propositional logic?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you need to introduce a private symbol "!" to denote negation of a "literal" proposition which seems not standard? Normally we just need Kripke relational semantics to turn modal logic to propositional/predicate logic, then you're free to use ND, Tableux, sequent or Hilbert calculi... For example following the question in your above comment, using Tableux similar to your above K-modus ponens proof one can easily prove axiom K (□(a→b)→□(a→□b)), it's not actually an axiom in non-Hilbert systems.

Comment: I like the symbol `!` because it lets me define a wff in negative normal form as simply being $\lnot$-free and shows which pairs of propositions can close a branch of a tableau. Yes, translations into FOL are certainly possible, but I've found that in general the result is not particularly compact or easy to typeset.

Comment: For me I'll try to minimize *private* language signatures if normal users in the community are not familiar with since ultimately the use of any language is for others to easily understand. As for the easiness to typeset for modal logic compared to FOL, it's probably  unavoidable anyway since its semantics in not in one world like FOL but has to look out for all accessible possible worlds and apply FOL there in any branch. The advantage and disadvantage of Hilbert system should be same compared to other systems here in modal logics...

Comment: Hmm okay, that makes sense; I took out the `!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, the first proof systems for normal modal logics were, not surprisingly, Hilbert systems. They are still heavily used in mathematical modal logic, because much work there is done in a model-theoretic vein and Hilbert systems come in handy for these purposes. That said, there are of course also natural deduction and sequent systems, but in the modal case these tend to get quite complicated and modal proof theory is still in its infancy. For a start on these non Hilbert systems I would suggest Heinrich Wansing's monograph 'Displaying Modal Logic', Dordrecht 1998.

In what follows I will outline the standard development of Hilbert systems for $K$ as found in the standard textbooks (Blackburn et al. 2000, Goldblatt 1990) and show how to justify the inference rule of interest.

Let a modal logic be a set of formulas containing all propositional tautologies and which is closed under modus ponens. A normal modal logic is a modal logic $\Phi$ that contains all instances of the $K$-axiom:

> $\Box (\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\Box \varphi \rightarrow \Box \psi),$

all instances of the duality-axiom:

> $\neg \Diamond \varphi \leftrightarrow \Box \neg \varphi$

and is closed under boxing:

> $\varphi \in \Phi \Rightarrow \Box \varphi \in \Phi$.

Obviously, for every set of formulas there is a smallest normal modal logic extending that set (the normal logic generated by the set). $K$ is then the normal logic generated by the empty set.

Finally, we can introduce a notion of derivability. For a normal modal logic $\Phi$, and a set of formulas $
\Psi \cup \{ \psi\}$ let $\psi$ be derivable from $\Psi$ in the logic $\Phi$, written $\Psi \vdash_{\Phi} \psi$, if $\psi \in \Phi \cup \Psi$.

It holds that $\{\Box(\varphi \rightarrow \psi), \Box \varphi\} \vdash_K \Box \psi$, since $\Box \psi$ is a member of $\Gamma:= K \cup \{ \Box(\varphi \rightarrow \psi), \Box \varphi \}$ which can be shown by the following sequence:

1. $\Box(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\Box \varphi \rightarrow \Box \psi) \in \Gamma $
2. $\Box (\varphi \rightarrow  \psi) \in \Gamma$
3. $\Box \varphi \rightarrow \Box \psi \in \Gamma$ 1,2
4. $\Box \varphi \in \Gamma$
5. $\Box \psi \in \Gamma$ 3,4.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I have a question about the proof at the bottom. It looks like $\Gamma$ is known to be inductively closed and we're showing that various things are inside it ... do we need to explicitly set $\Gamma$ to the deductive closure of $K \cup \{ \square(\varphi \to \psi), \square \varphi \} $ or am I misunderstanding the proof?